# ClassNotFoundException org.postgresql.Driver when trying to run wildly

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am trying to create a test application that accesses a postgres database using JavaEE and Wildly 9.

So I downloaded Wildfly 9 and followed [these instructions](http://developer-should-know.tumblr.com/post/127065962382/installing-postgresql-and-adding-data-source-to) to add the driver to it. When I run

```
/subsystem=datasources:installed-drivers-list
```

I get

```
{
            "driver-name" => "postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar",
            "deployment-name" => "postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar",
            "driver-module-name" => undefined,
            "module-slot" => undefined,
            "driver-datasource-class-name" => undefined,
            "driver-xa-datasource-class-name" => undefined,
            "driver-class-name" => "org.postgresql.Driver",
            "driver-major-version" => 9,
            "driver-minor-version" => 4,
            "jdbc-compliant" => false
        }
```

so it seems ok.

I also copied the jar ( postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar ) file to the deployment folder in Wildfly.

I added this dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
```

and this is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="postgres">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="test" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="test" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But overtime I try to run my application I get:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class :
>   org.postgresql.Driver

What am I missing? I can't find any other procedure to do in order to make it work. I am sitting in this problem for some hours now and I can't see anything else I can do.

edit: I created a data source and it works (so the dependencies are all there, there must be something wrong with the persistence.xml itself). I would rather have it working using the persistence.xml file, due to configurability.

here is my datasource as configured in the standalone.xml

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/PostgresDS" pool-name="PostgresDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/stats</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>postgresql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>test</user-name>
                        <password>test</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                </datasource>
```

Comment: You should accessyour database connection through a JNDI name defined in WildFly.

Comment: Ok, is there any reason for that? Or should the persistence.xml also work?

Comment: Did you add the postgres driver as a module like the article says or did you deploy the JAR? It looks like you deployed the JAR from the output.

Comment: No, I don't think it will work, not when you define a container (JTA) managed persistence connection AFAIK. You are telling JPA to let the contrainer manage the transaction, if so, you should also hand over transaction management to the container.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I did both of them

Comment: @MartijnBurger yes, it makes sense..

Comment: You don't really need or want to do both. I'd also advise using a managed connection too and not defining the connection in the persistence.xml.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Thanks! :)

Comment: @JSBach I have the same problem. Did you find solution?

I configured the driver correctly, and Test connection in the server console is working.

But for some reason I still get the same error. I also wrote the driver jndi-name in persitence.xml.